# Feign Client : Post a Map<String,Object> in Request Body => feign.FeignException: status 400 reading MAp

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign

When I Post `Map<String,Object>` using Feign Client , I get the Error Message :

> feign.FeignException: status 400 reading MAp .

Code

```
//Client side
@Component
@FeignClient(name = ServiceID.TACHE)
@RibbonClient(name = ServiceID.TACHE)
public interface ITacheService extends ITache {
@RequestMapping(value = TACHE_CONTROLLER + "/save", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    Map<String, Object> save(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> map);
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/task")
public class TaskController {

// Server side
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    Map<String, Object> save(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> map) throws ParseException { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need it to be a Map?

Try it with a Hashset or a HashMap like

```
//Client side
@Component
@FeignClient(name = ServiceID.TACHE)
@RibbonClient(name = ServiceID.TACHE)
public interface ITacheService extends ITache {
@RequestMapping(value = TACHE_CONTROLLER + "/save", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    HashMap<String, Object> save(@RequestBody HashMap<String,Object> map);
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/task")
public class TaskController {

// Server side
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    HashMap<String, Object> save(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> map) throws ParseException { }
}
```

or

```
//Client side
@Component
@FeignClient(name = ServiceID.TACHE)
@RibbonClient(name = ServiceID.TACHE)
public interface ITacheService extends ITache {
@RequestMapping(value = TACHE_CONTROLLER + "/save", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    HashSet<String, Object> save(@RequestBody HashSet<String,Object> set);
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/task")
public class TaskController {

// Server side
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    HashSet<String, Object> save(@RequestBody HashSet<String, Object> set) throws ParseException { }
}
```

Comment: Glad I helped you :D

Comment: Ewerton, did u mean HashSet<String> in the second snippet?